# SQL command works in MYSQL command line, but fails in NODE.JS app

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, node.js

The following SQL works fine if I enter it as root user:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bugtracker; CREATE DATABASE bugtracker; USE bugtracker;
```

but if I run the node.js code, I get error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE bugtracker; USE bugtracker' at line 1

errno: 1064,

sql: 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bugtracker; CREATE DATABASE bugtracker; USE bugtracker;',

sqlState: '42000',

sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DATABASE bugtracker; USE bugtracker' at line 1"

I have 2 node files, shown below. I have deleted appUser from mysql and re-added him, doing grant priveliges and flush privileges after.

Node files: mysql_funcs:

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

export function CreatePool()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        try
        {
            let pool = mysql.createPool({
                host: '127.0.0.1',
                user:'appUser',
                password: 'Password123'
            });
            resolve(pool);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}

export function GetDBSQL(sql, pool)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        try
        {
            let ret = pool.query(sql)
            resolve(ret);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}
```

and main.js:

```
import * as mysqlf from "../common/db/mysql_funcs.js"

mysqlf.CreatePool().then(
    (pool) =>
        {
                const sqll="DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bugtracker; CREATE DATABASE bugtracker; USE bugtracker;";

                mysqlf.GetDBSQL(sqll, pool).then(
                    (ans) =>
                    {
                        console.log("DONE OK");
                    },
                    (err) =>
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                )
            });
```

Comment: Support for multiple statements is disabled for security reasons (it allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not properly escaped). 

From the documentation it says you need to add a `multipleStatements?: boolean` to pool configuration if you want to run multiple statements inside of a single query

Comment: So how do I run multiple SQL statements from Node.js then?

Comment: Either run them in series or add the option I mentioned. I'm pretty sure this is at least part of the issue, that's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: It's better to run statements one at a time. There's practically no benefit to bunching them together.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, maybe it is preferable a migration approach, for example using knex js:

[Create database in Knex migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49690856/create-database-in-knex-migration)